# react-native how to move to next input after onpress "tab" key on keyboard

Tags: reactjs, react-native, keyboard-events, textinput

I used useRef to move to next input like this.

```
const passwordRef = useRef();
const onNext = (nextOne) => {
      nextOne?.current?.focus();
    };
...
return (
 <TextInput
          value={watch("username")}
          placeholder="Input Id"
          returnKeyType="next"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          placeholderTextColor={"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)"}
          onSubmitEditing={() => onNext(passwordRef)}
          onChangeText={(text) => setValue("username", text)}
        />
```

it worked with "enter" key, but I want to move to next input using "tab" key on the keyboard. Is there any way to implement this?

Comment: On an ipad with a magic keyboard connected via bluetooth tab triggers the onSubmitEditing event, does pressing tab actually enter a tab into the Textinput? You might try switching to the onChange event and inspect the event parameter to see if you can determine that the tab key was pressed, specifically event.nativeEvent